# Get a FieldMirror for a field on a package object

Tags: scala, reflection

I need to use reflection to get a field that is defined on a package object.

```
package com.coryklein

package object kittens {
  val purr = "meow"
}
```

The [Mirrors documentation](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.0-M5/scala-reflect/scala/reflect/api/Mirrors.html) says:

> Scala only has instance methods-- methods of objects are instance methods of object instances, obtainable via ModuleMirror.instance

There is even a generous example of using reflection to call a method `x` on a defined class `C`.

```
scala> class C { def x = 2 }
defined class C

scala> val im = m.reflect(new C)
im: reflect.runtime.universe.InstanceMirror = instance mirror for C@3442299e

scala> val methodX = typeOf[C].declaration(TermName("x")).asMethod
methodX: reflect.runtime.universe.MethodSymbol = method x

scala> val mm = im.reflectMethod(methodX)
mm: reflect.runtime.universe.MethodMirror = method mirror for C.x: scala.Int (bound to C@3442299e)

scala> mm()
res0: Any = 2
```

It seems that from here it shouldn't be too difficult to adapt the approach to reflecting a field that exists on an package object. However, a package object doesn't have a corresponding class to obtain the field from via reflection.

I have been able to obtain the term symbol:

```
val ts: TermSymbol = mirror.staticPackage("com.coryklein.kittens").info.decls
  .find(_.name.decodedName.toString == "purr").get.asTerm
```

But at this point, I don't have an instance mirror equivalent to `im` from above to reflect this field from.

How would I access the `purr` val defined in package object `kittens` via Scala reflection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The critical part here is finding the actual module, which ends up being named `com.coryklein.kittens.package$`:

```
scala>  import scala.reflect.runtime.{ universe => ru }

import scala.reflect.runtime.{universe=>ru}

scala> val runtimeMirror  = ru.runtimeMirror(getClass.getClassLoader)

runtimeMirror: reflect.runtime.universe.Mirror = JavaMirror with scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$TranslatingClassLoader@67ee3ed7 of type class scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$TranslatingClassLoader with classpath [(memory)] and parent being scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader$URLClassLoader@53b79b76 of type class scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader$URLClassLoader with classpath [file:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_111.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/resources.jar,file:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_111.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/rt.jar,file:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_111.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jsse.jar,file:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_111.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jce.jar,file:/Library/Jav...

scala> val moduleSymbol   = runtimeMirror.staticModule("com.coryklein.kittens.package$")

moduleSymbol: reflect.runtime.universe.ModuleSymbol = object package$

scala> val moduleMirror   = runtimeMirror.reflectModule(moduleSymbol)

moduleMirror: reflect.runtime.universe.ModuleMirror = module mirror for com.coryklein.kittens.package$ (bound to null)

scala> val moduleInstance = moduleMirror.instance

moduleInstance: Any = com.coryklein.kittens.package$@72d3f96

scala> val instanceMirror = runtimeMirror.reflect(moduleInstance)

instanceMirror: reflect.runtime.universe.InstanceMirror = instance mirror for com.coryklein.kittens.package$@72d3f96

scala> val fieldSymbol    = instanceMirror.symbol.info.member(ru.TermName("purr")).asTerm.accessed.asTerm

fieldSymbol: reflect.runtime.universe.TermSymbol = value purr

scala> val fieldMirror    = instanceMirror.reflectField(fieldSymbol)

fieldMirror: reflect.runtime.universe.FieldMirror = field mirror for private[this] val purr: java.lang.String (bound to com.coryklein.kittens.package$@72d3f96)

scala> fieldMirror.get

res0: Any = meow

scala>
```

I figured out the name of the module by poking around in my `target/scala-2.12/classes` directory, and running `javap` here and there.